# Pythonic way to count keys of multiple dicts

Tags: python, counter

Lets say there are 3 dictionaries `first`, `second`, `third` with following values

```py
first = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.001}
second = {'a': 0.99, 'c': 0.78}
third = {'c': 1, 'd': 0.1}
total = {'_first': first, '_second': second, '_third':third}
```

Is there a way to **quickly** get a data structure which can hold the information of the count of each key (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) using *`total`* instead of multiple dictionaries. For example, the answer should return something like `{'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':2, 'd':1}` since `a`, `b`, `c` key occurred twice while `d` occurred only once in these dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
first = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.001}
second = {'a': 0.99, 'c': 0.78}
third = {'c': 1, 'd': 0.1}
print(Counter(chain(first, second, third)))
```

to account for edited question with variable number of dicts stored in a dict `total`

```
total = {'_first': first, '_second': second, '_third':third}
print(Counter(chain.from_iterable(total.values())))
```

Comment: Thanks. `chain` seems to faster than the method @ajax1234 suggested. Is there any reason for this ?

Comment: As it says in the docs: "The [itertools] module standardizes __a core set of fast, memory efficient tools__ that are useful by themselves or in combination. Together, they form an “iterator algebra” making it possible to construct specialized tools succinctly and efficiently in pure Python."

Comment: Thanks. I will learn to use itertools more. I have edited the question to include the possibility of variable number of dictionaries with in the `total` dictionary. Is it possible for you to edit the answer to account for this. Sorry for the question edit.

Comment: Any reason to create dict of dicts and not list/tuple of dicts?

Comment: Yeah. The keys of `total` are important for the application that I am writing. So `_first_` represents a timestamp and the dictionary represents its values. So I am trying to count the number of times, `a` / `b` etc appeared in the given timestamps (keys of `total`)

Comment: @RTM Unsure what exactly you were looking for, but my solution doesn't use imports and appears notably faster than this solution for you given example

Answer (score 1):

Without any imports:

```py
def dict_keys_count(*dicts):
    keys = []
    for _dict in dicts:
        keys += _dict.keys()

    keys_counts = {}
    for key in set(keys):
        keys_counts[key] = keys.count(key)

    return keys_counts
```

```py
print(dict_keys_count(first,second,third))
# {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 'a': 2}
```

---

**Speed comparison**: my vs accepted answer

```py
from time import time

t0 = time()
for _ in range(int(1e7)):
    dict_keys_count(first,second,third)
print("No-import solution {}:".format(time() - t0))
# 17.77

t0 = time()
for _ in range(int(1e7)):
    Counter(chain(first, second, third))
print("Accepted solution {}:".format(time() - t0))
# 24.01
```

Comment: This would be more clear if you used OP's input data.  Also, can you demonstrate how this is faster than the earlier solutions?

Comment: Why is it _more_ pythonic to eschew the python libraries?

Comment: I think in many cases "without any imports" is good because they aren't necessary, but that is for third party libraries like using `pandas` when you don't actually need it. `itertools` and `collections` are core python libraries so I don't think avoiding them is useful at all.

Comment: @Prune Done - may differ for more complex cases, don't know, but it'd be outside of OP's question

Comment: @Lagerbaer They're redundant, since it can be done using barebone built-ins - which are more debuggable, and don't require knowledge of high-level libraries. Explicitness and clarity are Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections
first = {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.001}
second = {'a': 0.99, 'c': 0.78}
third = {'c': 1, 'd': 0.1}
r = dict(collections.Counter([*first, *second, *third]))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks. The chain option used by @buran seems to be faster while iterating over the dictionaries